# Strange Graphite graph rendition after a certain amount of minutes

Tags: graphite

I am graphing stats sent from Logstash to StatsD to Graphite. When I view my graphite graphs, I see the correct data for the most recent 4 minutes and then the graph has a huge drop off to about 1/10th of the data metrics. As the graph refreshes, the drop continues to happen at the rolling 4 minute mark.

The metrics I am currently graphing are being sent from StatsD from Logstash. They are status codes counts in the form of:

```
sum(stats_counts.logstash.*.iis.*.2*)
sum(stats_counts.logstash.*.iis.*.3*)
sum(stats_counts.logstash.*.iis.*.4*)
sum(stats_counts.logstash.*.iis.*.5*)
```

I have Graphite set up with the following configs:

storage-schemas.conf:

```
[catchall]
pattern = ^.*
retentions = 10s:7d,1m:60d,10m:1y
```

storage-aggregation.conf:

```
[min]
pattern = \.min$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[max]
pattern = \.max$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[count]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[lower]
pattern = \.lower(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = min

[upper]
pattern = \.upper(_\d+)?$
xFilesFactor = 0.1
aggregationMethod = max

[sum]
pattern = \.sum$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum

[gauges]
pattern = ^.*\.gauges\..*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = last

[default_average]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.5
aggregationMethod = average
```

I have removed all whisper files and restarted the carbon cache service so that I can rule out a previous schema being saved in the whisper file. This also happens with the corresponding `stats.` metrics (in addition to the above `stats_counts.` metric).

The most confusing part here is that this is happening at the 4 minute mark as opposed to the 1 minute or 10 minute mark as configured in my `storage-schemas.conf`. If anything strange were to happen, I would imagine it would happen at one of those set intervals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only think of following the logs (`tail -f`). See carbon.conf to enable them.